# Lua randomseed funcionar só dentro de um corpo (do)

Tags: lua

Programo Lua a bastante tempo, mas quase nunca precisei trabalhar com `math.randomseed`, pesquisei e não encontrei nada informando sobre isso, fiz alguns teste e nenhum funcionou como eu esperava. A função `math.randomseed` altera o valor da seed do `math.random`, mas precisava que essa seed fosse alterada somente dentro de um corpo `do` e ao sair dele voltasse ao valor anterior, eu sei que o padrão é `os.time()`, mas no código a seed pode ser alterada para outra qualquer.

Exemplo:

```
math.randomseed(10) --> não tenho acesso a essa parte do código
do --> parte do código que tenho acesso
    math.randomseed(50)
    ...
end --> até aqui a seed teria q ser 50
--> aqui a seed teria que voltar a ser 10
```

fiz um código:

```
math.oldrandomseed = math.randomseed
math.randomseed = function(seed)
    math.seed = seed
    math.oldrandomseed(seed)
end
```

assim saberia qual a seed anterior, mas teria que ter acesso a parte externa do código pra poder executá-lo no inicio (fora do `do`), a questão é: Tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem sair do `do`?

Comment: Não é possível recuperar a seed. Qual o problema real que você está tentando resolver com isso?

Comment: Eu estava criando uma função que precisaria utilizar o `math.randomseed` porém não queria "estragar" o código ja em execução, pq a pessoa poderia estar utilizando `math.randomseed` em algum lugar